# Unable to restore .bck files on SQL Server 2014 Express edition

Tags: sql-server

I'm unable to restore `.bck` files on SQL Server 2014 Express edition.

The `.bck` file size is more than 10 GB, I used SQL Server Management Studio to restore the backup files and error I'm getting is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE
>   failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed
>   your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: Which part of *... failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB...* do you *not* understand?? SQL Server **Express** is free - but limited to 10 GB - and you're trying to restore something that's **bigger** than 10 GB - that just won't work. Period.

Answer (score 1):

This is because SQL Server Express edition has limitations:

> Maximum relational Database size  - 10 GB

For more details see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)